# Use constructor of an object inside an object

Tags: java, object

Im trying to use the constructor of the `class Axe(Arma)` represented as an object inside of `Player(Heroi)`, but simply doing `Player.Axe.setAtaque()` doesn't work, please help me!

```
package Items;

public class Arma extends Item {
    private int ataque;

    public int getAtaque() {
        return ataque;
    }

    public void setAtaque (int attack) {
        this.ataque = attack;
    }

}
```

Class Heroi:

```
package Personagens;

import Items.*;

public class Heroi extends Personagem{
    Mochila Backpack = new Mochila();
    Cinto Belt = new Cinto();
    Bracelete Bracelet = new Bracelete();
    Arma Axe = new Arma();
}
```

Main class:

```
package guiaPOO;

import Personagens.*;

public class main {
    public static void main( String [] args) {
        Heroi Player = new Heroi();

        /* This Doesnt Work */
        Player.Axe.setAtaque();
    }
}
```

The `weapon(Arma)` I've created as an object in class `Heroi` doesn't even show up when trying to access or modify it in main.

Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Read about instances vs classes

Comment: Some recommendations, when you use variables use them with low case (ie: Heroi player = new Heroi();). Also the default scope for attributes is package , since you don't define your Axe attribute as public, you could not access it. Also, as you already have in Arma, it's better to define attributes as private with getters & setters. Last, the setAtaque method needs an integer as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify `public`, `protected` or `private`, members of a class get what is known as *package access*.

Because `Axe` has package access, it is only accessible from within the package (`Personagens`) containing it.

Just add `public` in front of the field declarations, like this:

```
public Mochila Backpack = new Mochila();
public Cinto Belt = new Cinto();
public Bracelete Bracelet = new Bracelete();
public Arma Axe = new Arma();
```

and they will be accessible from any code. (Of course, if you want some of them to *not* be accessible from any code, then don't add it to those fields)

Comment: Thanks, but how can i managed to acess them without making they all public ?

Comment: @ViniciusIlidio You could make some of them public (only the ones you want to access). Or you could make public methods that access them.

Comment: can you please show me an example on how to make those methods ?

Comment: @ViniciusIlidio `public Arma getAxe() {return Axe;}` ? Or `public void attack(int damage) {Axe.attack(damage);}`?

Comment: Where would i add that method, main ?

Comment: @ViniciusIlidio It looks like you don't understand methods (yet) - in which case, why do you want to use one instead of just making the field public?

Comment: This project is for a subject in college, and one of the things the professor will rate is properly encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

`Player.Axe.setAtaque();` You haven't passed a parameter to the `setAtaque` method. It should be something like `Player.Axe.setAtaque(5);`

Comment: It is not about passing values or not, the method setAtaque doest show up neither does Axe. I'm trying to find a way to manipulate the values of the weapon using constructors and methods that i've alredy defined in the project

Comment: That's strange, I compiled the code myself and they both showed up and compiled without trouble.

Comment: You've managed to define the axe attack inside of main using     Player.Axe.setAtaque(5); ?

Comment: Check default scope for attributes and your packages. @Vinicius Ilidio Check the comment in your question.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6i5e6s Like Patrick said its probably an issue with your packages